# List of Items on Form with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, jquery-plugins

I have two questions:

I am developing a web system in asp.net mvc with jquery and there several registers of documents where each document has multiple authors and I intend to do this in the view (form) of the same document (including several authors like a list) and then to the end (post), save everything in a single transaction. My question is, is there any jquery plugin that facilitates this mechanism on client-side? Or if anyone has an idea of ​​how to develop it?

It's not a single string list, this list of authors, has about 5 fields (2 combos, second text, a checkbox), need to find a way to climb a complete list of these in the post to persist. How could I take this objects on my Action ?

PS: I can't use Checkboxes to do this because I'll have a lot of authors, and the user will select it on a modal with jquery ui.

Thanks

### Edits

Sample: jsbin.com/uvajec/2/edit
I dont know if it works fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

1 - Using normal form submit, just adopting convention names for the inputs of the form. [This link](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx) explains how you can use the MVC Model Binding to a list.

2 - Using ajax post, sending a complex js object to the server in json format (doesn't have to be json, but it's easier). [This link](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/15/sending-json-to-an-asp-net-mvc-action-method-argument.aspx) shows how you do it.

Comment: I've seen the first link before, but I don't know how to create a jquery script to do a bind list? Do you have an example? Thank you!

Comment: In the first link, you won't use jquery because it's not an ajax post, it's just a normal form submit. In this submit, the names of the parameters being posted should follow a pattern that the MVC Model Binder can understand, in order to transform them into a complex object in your controller action. There's no actual binding, everything works based on convention names. By the way, in that same link there is a sample project included.

Comment: if you choose the second option, and there's something specific in jquery that you can't do, it would help a lot if you'd post the html code for the case.

Comment: Hi Felipe (xará hehe) thanks for your awser. Now I udnerstood. I have an sample... I need something dynamic because some documents can has 30 authors and others just one or two... take a look at this link (http://jsbin.com/uvajec/2/edit) I just did it now... I don't know if it's a nice code... but I based on Phill's code (first sample) and I don't know if it will works with Mvc Model Binder of asp.net mvc. What is your opinion? If you want to change the code, be free! Thanks again! []s

Comment: I've just tested your code on MVC. I made a few changes to make it work, and put it a comment with the model I used on the server. Check it out: http://jsbin.com/uvajec/4/edit

Comment: Thanks so much Felipe! It will help me a lot... I'll try to implement (delete and update method in this list). Thanks! []'s